# Are there new conditions for Getting the EU Blue Card in Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card, labor-law

I have an interesting situation, I do have a Blue Card already, but they are saying it was issued wrongly. The Foreigner Office is checking what they can do. I already live and work here. They say potentially, they need to give me another visa. What will happen to me?

Are there new changes applied to the blue card requirements in Germany.

Is it possible to get a blue card if I don't have an University Degree, but having a high salary, eg.: 75k

Is it possible to get the blue card?

I am an IT specialist.

I of course want the Blue Card Advantages.

Here is a very interesting link, but I still don't fully understand it:
https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beschv_2013/BJNR149910013.html

Comment: You definitely need a (recognized) university degree (that's a German, not EU-wide, requirement, the directive allows countries to define ways to compensate the lack of a degree through profesionnal experience). It's not new but does suggest there was originally a mistake (which is not quite the same thing). I am not sure whether there are any legal remedies that would be open to you.

Comment: @Gala , that's an interesting situation - I remember a friend of mine getting a blue card in Germany. And he did not have a degree also. It was due to its salary amount. Maybe you have a chance

Comment: @Gala - According to this Web Site, it would be ok to have the blue card, by having the "5 years" experience, in case of no degree.
 http://www.eu-bluecard.com/eu-blue-card-germany/

Comment: @HelloWorldGuy To the best of my knowledge, that's not the case in Germany. I suspect the site's authors just copy-pasted their generic blue card page (although, strangely, they only have a country-specific page for Germany). It's easy to get confused because this rule is in the directive, which means that countries could allow people without university degrees to apply based on their professional experience (that's what I referred to in my first comment).

Comment: IIRC, it's even been transcribed in German law but it's not been implemented yet because the ministry still needs to publish a regulation to do that. I think we had several earlier questions about that, you can search for "blue card + Germany" to find more details.