# Getting the Permanent Residence Permit In Germany with and without the Blue Card

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit, blue-card

In this question I asked about new conditions or changes for the blue card:

[Are there new conditions for Getting the EU Blue Card in Germany?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9409/are-there-new-conditions-for-getting-the-eu-blue-card-in-germany)

Now I want to know, if I don't have the blue card, and I am working with IT in Germany, with a regular/alternative permit.

What are the steps I need to take to get the **Permanent Residence Permit**?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by “permanent residence permit"?

Comment: @Gala - I mean the right to live in Germany without the need to have a Job or study, if for instance, I want to stay 6 months not working, just studying on my own.

Comment: OK, I think the Niederlassungserlaubnis I mentioned in my answer is indeed what you want.

Comment: @Gala - And for changes Job under the normal work permit, do you know how it works(I work as Software Engineer)? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the details or what you can expect in practice. My understanding is that your permit can come with some restrictions but it's not always the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 5 years, you will become a “long-term resident” under EU law but it does not make all that much of a difference.

After 5 years, you can also apply for a *Niederlassungserlaubnis* but there are a number of conditions to meet, most importantly:

- Having contributed to the social security system for 60 months
- Knowing (some) German
- Having a job, sufficient means of existence and room to live in
- Good morality (and in particular no criminal conviction)

The requirements for Blue card holders are somewhat lighter (e.g. 21 or 33 months instead of 60, depending on your knowledge of German). “Simple” knowledge of German is required in any case.

It is permanent in the sense that once you have it, you have a stronger protection against any removal and don't need to regularly renew it and prove you still meet the conditions (you do need to get a new document with a new photo once in a while, including when you get a new passport but that's a formality). You are also free to take any job or stop working without threatening your right to stay in the country. You can however lose it if you leave Germany for more than 6 months.

Comment: By "you 'can' lose it after you leave Germany for more than 6 months", do you mean the regulations explicitly stipulate that this person must not leave Germany for 6 months consecutively, or is this a mere "possibility"? I never knew this part of the regulation and it seems pretty strict, similar to US requirements. What about Blue Card then. Do you also lose the Blue Card after being out of work/leaving for a certain amount of time?

Comment: @JiXiang Actually, it's more than that, the *Niederlassungserlaubnis* automatically expires (*erlischt*) if you leave for more than six months. There is however a procedure to ask for permission to leave beforehand to avoid that.

Comment: @JIXiang Regarding the Blue Card, it might be worth asking another question about that. The relevant EU directive provides that countries can refuse to renew it if you have been unemployed for more than three months but countries can be more generous. For example, in France, if you are unemployed when the times come to renew it, you get a new permit giving you one more year to look for work in France. And you can always stay in the country as long as you get unemployment benefits (which can be up to 2 years). Not sure about Germany.

Comment: But leaving and being out of work are two different things. In France, you can stay for quite some time after losing your job but you have to be looking for work and available so you have to remain in France (if you want to keep the benefit of the permit, obviously). In Germany, going abroad at the behest of your employer is actually mentioned in the law as an exception to the 6-month abroad rule.

Comment: @JiXiang I just looked up the relevant part of the law and there are a number of other exceptions: For example if you lived for 15 years in Germany or you are in a relationship (not necessarily married) with someone who is either a permanent resident themselves or a German citizen, you can leave for six months without losing the benefit of your *Niederlassungserlaubnis*.

Comment: Thanks. That's really detailed information. You always offer great answers on this site.

Comment: If you can ask for permission then isn't the whole point lost then? Is there any restrictions about this permission? You already wrote up a lot of answer. Maybe you can just point me to the corresponding section of the German law and I might take a look myself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JiXiang The law isn't very specific on that. I think you have to provide a good reason to be out of the country for more than six months and they can refuse. That would be the point of the procedure. But I am just guessing at this point.

Comment: There are many various options to avoid expiration of the permanent residence permit. See https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/aufenthalt/erloeschen-eines-aufenthaltstitels/ for details.

Comment: @AndreySapegin I wrote “can” as a sneaky way to avoid getting into these details ;) But thanks for the link, will definitely be interesting to many people.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something curious:

> The European Union Blue Card directive applies to highly qualified
>   non-EU nationals seeking to be admitted to the territory of a Member
>   State of the European Union (common European Union immigration
>   policy), excluding Denmark, Ireland and the United Kingdom, for more
>   than three months for the purposes of employment and residence. The EU
>   Blue card also allows qualifying individuals to bring their close
>   family with them.

Is this correct?

Comment: Would you please put in a link reference to this quote? It almost looks as if you are asking a separate question.